# POST request from React to Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, axios

So I'm having an issue making a post request from React to my Express server backend: the request payload is correctly structured as far as I can tell, and I'm able to send back a hardcoded response from server and receive it in the frontend.

**However, the problem is it seems like the data itself is not reaching the server - when I console.log(req.body) on server it's `undefined`.** I'm totally stumped.

Network tab when I inspect request:

- Headers status is 200, request completed
- the Payload shows the json object correctly formatted `body: {url: "https://example.com"}`
- the Response returns correctly too! `{response: "foo"}`

Client-side API function:

```js
const callBackendAPI = async (query) => {
        const response = await axios.post('/', {
            body: { url: query },
        });
    }
```

Note: I've added `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` to the client's package.json.

In server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // <------ **Here's the issue, there's nothing here**
    res.json({ response: 'foo' });
    // however, if I send res.json(req.body), the response is empty in Network tab
});
```

Comment: Are you using a body parser

Comment: FML. no. i'm not.

Comment: just like this? 
`const bodyParser = require('body-parser');`

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Comment: Yeah any config should work

Comment: Try with ``App.use(express.json());``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the body-parser lib:

Install using:
`npm install body-parser`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // <------ **Here's the issue, there's nothing here**
    res.json({ response: 'foo' });
    // however, if I send res.json(req.body), the response is empty in Network tab
});
```

Apparently they've added `express.json()` back since 4.16.0 according to https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0 . So you could also use `express.json()` without installing body-parser.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // <------ **Here's the issue, there's nothing here**
    res.json({ response: 'foo' });
    // however, if I send res.json(req.body), the response is empty in Network tab
});
```